# How to open QTP from JavaScript without using ActiveXObject?

Tags: javascript, qtp, activexobject

i need to invoke QTP from a javascript without using ActiveXObject. can anybody guide me how to proceed with this?

Thanks,
Ramya.

Comment: Whilst I don't want to second guess your reasons, could you please tell us why you don't want to use ActiveXObject? (just curious)

Answer (score 0):

Java Script programming cannot be done in QTP but it will
support Java script. We can make a DLL by using Java script
and add that to QTP and there after you can use that.

Regards,
Mannusanghi

Comment: or you can use vbScript in addition for that.

Comment: i need javascript to automate QTP only not for writing scripts in QTP.i need to just open QTP and run test suites in it. i have this script like this..
 var qtApp = new ActiveXObject("QuickTest.Application"); // Create the application object 
qtApp.Launch(); // Start QuickTest 
qtApp.Visible = true // Make it visible  

But i dont want to use that ActiveXObject. Please guide me.

Thanks,
Ramya.

Answer (score 0):

QTP supplies a COM interface for automation, in order to create the automation object you **need** to use `ActiveXObject` (see this article on using [OLE Automation in Javascript](http://www.webreference.com/js/column55/activex.html)).

Why do you want to avoid using `ActiveXObject`?

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason why you don't want to use the ActiveXObject?

Anyhow, if you're running JavaScript through the Windows Script Host, instead of the way mentioned in the manual:

```
var qtApp = new ActiveXObject("QuickTest.Application");
```

...you can do this:

```
var qtApp = WScript.CreateObject("QuickTest.Application"); 
qtApp.Launch(); 
qtApp.Visible = true;
```

But you be might using ActiveX behind the scenes there anyway, I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Thank you so much. i read about the disadvantages of ActiveX like Security model and browser dependence. so i just wanted to avoid using it.